# How to Create a Free iOS Development Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios

I'm developing an app for learning purpose. Recently got to now that i can test the app in device without paying $99. I R&D on this but couldn't get succeed.Please, let me know if any way.
Thanks.

Comment: I find this question perfect and straight to the point

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You don't need to pay for the app running your own device. Just create a developer account and login to your Xcode. Select your own personal team and create provisioning profile.

Comment: This required 99$ for me.

Comment: And where do you answer how to "create provisioning profile"?

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to pay for running on your own device, but if you use a Paid-only API (see below note), then you can't even build without paying.

1. Open Xcode preferences.
2. Go to accounts add your apple id (free account).
3. Open your project.
4. Add display name and bundle identifier (com.exampledomain.app).
5. Check Automatically manage signing checkbox.
6. Select your team.
7. Attach your device and give a try after selecting your device from device selection.

> **Note** that above works unless you use a Paid-only API, I mean for example, the capability to sell things with "Apple Pay" would force you to purchase Paid-Apple-Developer-Account.

Comment: Thanks Hasan, I've already got the solution.

Comment: one cannot simply go to accounts. where is accounts?

Comment: open your xcode 
on top left corner near apple icon you shall see Xcode click on it ... see prefences click it you will see a popup in there you will have accounts